# Elderberry Proximity to Other Berries?

Tags: raspberries, elderberries

I was just gifted two elderberry vines (one Adams and one Johns variety), but I also already have two healthy black raspberry plants growing in my backyard. I read somewhere that black raspberries should be planted at least 300 feet away from any wild berry bushes on account of the possibility of disease spreading between them.  I am wondering whether this information also applies to the relationship between elderberry and black raspberry, as my yard is not large enough to accommodate a 300' distance between them.  Would it be potentially detrimental to the black raspberries if I planted the elderberries in my backyard?

Comment: I had wild elderberries growing within 10 feet of blackcaps (wild black raspberries) with no issues. This is anecdotal though, and your diseases might not apply to my region. Where in the world do you live? And elderberries are large shrubs, not vines - Adams, for example, can get 10 feet by 10 feet. Do you have room for a shrub that large in your yard?

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.  I live in NJ, and I do have a significant amount of space set aside for these elderberry shrubs (good correction).  They won't be immediately next to the black raspberries, but they will be within 100 feet or so.